# MYSQL join one colum from one table to two count() in another

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a table that stores a ranking for an online game. This table (Players) has 4 columns (Player_ID, Player_Name, Current_ELO and Player_Status). I want to show the games won/lost as well, but that info is in the Replays table, which has one row per each individual game.
I can easily count the number of won games or lost games with the count(*) function:

```
select Winner, count(*) from Replays group by Winner;
select Loser, count(*) from Replays group by Loser;
```

However, I cannot find a way to join both tables so my final result is something like:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Player_Name | Current_ELO | Won games | Lost games |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| John        | 1035        | 5         | 3          |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

My best guess is  this, however returns too many results because I cannot group the "count()" by Winner/Loser individually for each count:

```
select Player_Name,  Current_ELO, Player_Status, count(Winner_Replays.Winner), count(Loser_Replays.Loser) from Players
inner join Replays as Winner_Replays on Winner_Replays.Winner = Players.Player_Name
inner join Replays as Loser_Replays on Loser_Replays.Loser = Players.Player_Name
group by Winner_Replays.Winner order by Current_ELO desc;
```

Ideally, as some players might have 0 wins or 0 losses, I would like that it returns 0 for those users, if that is possible at all. Thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of Replays table ? Can you give a sample of data for that table for any player ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following using a `INNER JOIN` on a list of players with their result of the replay. You can use `SUM` with `CASE` to get the count of wins / defeats of each player.

```
SELECT Players.Player_Name, ANY_VALUE(Current_ELO), ANY_VALUE(Player_Status),
  SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Lost_Games, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Won_Games
FROM Players INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 'W' AS result, Winner AS Player_Name FROM Replays
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L', Loser FROM Replays
) win_lose ON Players.Player_Name = win_lose.Player_Name
GROUP BY Players.Player_Name
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(Current_ELO) DESC;
```

You can also use the `LEFT JOIN` solution like this:

```
SELECT Players.Player_Name, ANY_VALUE(Current_ELO) AS Current_ELO, ANY_VALUE(Player_Status) AS Player_Status,
  COUNT(DISTINCT rLoser.ReplayID) AS Lost_Games, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT rWinner.ReplayID) AS Won_Games
FROM Players
  LEFT JOIN Replays AS rWinner ON rWinner.Winner = Players.Player_Name
  LEFT JOIN Replays AS rLoser ON rLoser.Loser = Players.Player_Name
GROUP BY Players.Player_Name
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(Current_ELO) DESC;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d645a251383fbd926a441e68f4e89b25)

Comment: This is very promising, however I get many results for each player, not the correct sum (also, the quantity for wins and loses is the same.

Comment: Your code is wonderful! However, and for some reason, it works very well when players have little replays. However, when I use it in my database players with more than a few replays associated get a very high number, which is if I am not mistaken the multiplication of their Wins and their Loses.

Comment: you saw the update? you have to use inner join with sub-query.

Comment: yes, I saw. Now works like a charm. Many many thanks for your help!